# How to repeat href URL in string and then add extra characters between

Tags: jquery, string, url

I need to get an existing URL from an href and repeat it with some extra characters in between (in order to trigger a popup).

For example
`<div class="item"><a href="https://website.com"></a></div>`

Would become `<div class="item"><a href="https://website.com?modal-link=https://website.com"></a></div>`

I'm pretty sure I'm getting the terminology incorrect and therefore my searches are not getting results for what I'm trying to achieve!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: would you like to do this for all `a` tags on your page?

Comment: Ah no, just ones that exist within a div with class of 'item'. Will amend in post, thanks!

Comment: modal-link will be static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all anchor tags (`<a>`) on in your div with the class `item` using `$('.item a')` and then loop over each using `.each`. When looking at a specific anchor tag you can get it's current `href` by using `$(this).attr("href")` and then modify it to have the link added to the end of it.

Lastly, you can update the current anchor tag by using `$(this).attr('href', href);`

See working example below:

```js
$('.item a').each(function() {
  let href = $(this).attr('href'); // get href from the anchor tag
  href += "?modal-link=" + href; // add the query string to it
  $(this).attr('href', href); // update the href attribute
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://website.com">My Link (same)</a>
<div class="item">
  <a href="https://website.com">My Link (changes)</a>
  <br/>
  <a href="https://website2.com">My Link2 (changes)</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks good! Should this go in (document).ready(function() at all? It's not working for me as it is.

Comment: @user2188661 yeah, it should go in the `$(document).ready(function() {// here})` does that work?